# OpenCL not giving proper output for String Matching program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencl, intel-xdk

Iam trying to learn OpenCL with VC++ in Visual Studio 2013 Community. I installed OpenCL from Intel XDK since my hardware is "i5 CPU" and "Intel HD Graphics 4000 GPU" 16 cores.

I wrote in "kernel.cl" the following content
here 'pCount' refers to Pattern Count ("babb" => 4) and 'lim' refers string length => 10

```
__kernel void vsearch( __global char* str, __global char* pat, __global int* res, const int pCount, const unsigned int lim)
{
    int tid = get_global_id(0);
    int flag = 1;
    if(tid < (lim - pCount)) {
        flag = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < pCount; i++){
            if(str[tid + i] != pat[i])
                flag = 0;
        }
        if(flag == 1)
            res[0] = tid;
   }
}
```

I invoked it in Visual Studio VC++ with the following program

```
#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS

#include "cl.hpp"
#include "util.hpp"

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
using namespace cl;

#ifndef DEVICE
#define DEVICE CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT
#endif

#include "err_code.h"

int main(void)
{
    vector<char> str(10), pat(4);
    vector<int> res(1);
    Buffer d_str, d_pat, d_res;

    string s = "aababbabcb";
    string p = "babb";

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        str.push_back(s[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        pat.push_back(p[i]);
    }

    try
    {
        Context context(DEVICE);
        Program program(context, util::loadProgram("kernel.cl"), true);
        CommandQueue queue(context);
        make_kernel<Buffer, Buffer, Buffer, int, int> vsearch(program, "vsearch");

        d_str = Buffer(context, str.begin(), str.end(), true);
        d_pat = Buffer(context, pat.begin(), pat.end(), true);
        d_res = Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int));

        vsearch(EnqueueArgs(queue, NDRange(str.size())), d_str, d_pat, d_res, 4, 10);

        copy(queue, d_res, res.begin(), res.end());

        cout << res[0];
    }
    catch (Error err) {
        cout << "Exception\n";
        cerr << "ERROR: " << err.what() << "(" << err_code(err.err()) << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The output in the console is "5", but it should be "2"

Thank You.

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio 2013]

[image]

Comment: What is this doing? `copy(queue, d_res, res.begin(), res.end());` Copying outside of the device the result using proper CL calls, or copying as if it was a vector?

Comment: Sorry for very late reply, I guess it is copying from the device to host. I declared res as a vector of size 1 and have only one element inside it.